# Vue.js reactivity of data object property not triggered when using v-model

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-reactivity

I have a component with data containing an object, this object has a property which is an array.

```html
<template>
    <div>
        <product-selector :selected-products="order.selectedProducts" v-model="order.selectedProducts"/>
    </div>
</template>
```

```js
data () {
    return {
        order: {
            selectedProducts: [],
        },
    };
}
```

Everytime a new product is selected/deselected in product-selector, I emit an "input" event with the new array. The problem is that the order object in the parent component is not reactive and is not triggering the new rendering events. If I don't use an "order" object but directly a "selectedProducts" array it works, but I don't want to use this solution. Later I need to pass the order object to other components.

Comment: Can you show code where event is emitted?

Comment: The event is emitted correctly, and it works if I use directly an array in v-model instead of object property. Problem is that the object is not reactive.

Comment: Vue has some reactivity limits, it depends on how you change `selectedProducts` array.

Comment: I'm aware of the limits, that's why I said "new array" to let you know it's a new reference ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can make your object like:
order: {

```
        selectedProducts: [],
        key:0
    },
```

and your template

```
<product-selector :selected-products="order.selectedProducts" v-model="order" :key="order.key/>
```

and when you emit the new selected products increment the order key

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make the components 'reactive', you have to emit data up from the child component to the parent component, and then in the parent component, you have to react to the emitted events.
You can read more about it in the documentation here:
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Using-v-model-on-Components

Pay attention to this part:

> For this to actually work though, the  inside the component
> must:
>
> Bind the value attribute to a value prop On input, emit its own custom
> input event with the new value